# pass queryset and retrieve in template

Tags: python, django

Hate to ask such a simple question (I spent hours trying to solve it). I watched tons of tutorials and posts (also on this site) all explain the same thing but I can't access my data on the template.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import YTLink

def ytlinks(request):
    queryset = YTLink.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'links/home.html', {'queryset':queryset}, content_type='application/xhtml+xml')
```

home.html

```
{% extends "links/header.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% if queryset %}
queryset is filled
{% else %}
queryset is not filled
{% endif %}

<br> <br> <br>

{% for ytlink in queryset %}
    <a href="{{ ytlink.link }}">{{ ytlink.link }}></a><br>
{% endfor %}
```

My queryset is never filled. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: did you check your queryset content with manage's shell ?

Comment: What is rendered in the browser?

Comment: Does your queryset definitely contain results?

Comment: it does contain results, i checked in the shell. 
how can i see what is rendered in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def ytlinks(request):
    try:
        queryset = YTLink.objects.all()
    except:
        queryset = None
    return render(request, 'links/home.html', {'queryset':queryset}, content_type='application/xhtml+xml')
```

in home.html
change

```
{% if queryset %}
```

to

```
{% if queryset is not None %}
```